# metodo logout en laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Esoty intentando aplicar un logout en mi proyecto laravel 5.5 con este metodo:

```
Route::get('/logout', function () {

        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('login');
    })->name('auth_logout');
```

Pero cuando doy click en el back del navegador me retorna a la pagina anterior que estaba y el usuario aun se encuentra autenticado cuando debería haberse eliminado la sesión.

He creado un middleware para lidiar con esto:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Este middleware me funciona; pero siento que este método no es efectivo del todo porque si damos click varias veces seguidas en el back llega un momento en el que retorna a la pagina anterior y el usuario sigue autenticado.

Existirá alguna forma de eliminar la sesión en laravel cuando ejecuto el `logout()` para que automáticamente se redirija al login. Revisando el método `logout()` de `Auth` este se encuentra vacío.

Sldos

Comment: No puedo mirar ahora pero esto ya fue preguntado, realiza una búsqueda en el sitio.

Comment: Puedes poner en la pagina login un script que sobrescriba la dirección a donde se dirigirá la página al presionar el botón de back.

Comment: Verifica esta respuesta seguro te ayudara, puedes escribir si te funciono o no: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585416/how-to-logout-and-redirect-to-login-page-using-laravel-5-4